# subtotal calculation on the fly in Cognos 10.1.1

Tags: cognos, subtotal

My reports have a lot of subtotals due to which the size of csv file has increased from 3 MB to 9 MB. This has made subtotal rendering very slow.

If the report is Department vs. stores Sales Unit, reports looks like

```
department stores sales_unit     
    1         1      500 
    10        2      600 
subtotal for 10      1100
    11        1      550 
    11        2      650 
subtotal for 11      1200 
overall total        2300
```

the query would pull data in this form

```
10;1;500;1100;2300 
10;2;600;1100;2300 
11;1;550;1200;2300 
11;2;650;1200;2300
```

But I want the query to pull just this

```
10;1;500 
10;2;600 
11;1;550 
11;2;650
```

and then do the subtotal calculation in memory. My whole point is- since dept_subtotal and overall_total are getting pulled as a column, they repeat across all rows. My actual report has 25 columns each column having 5 metrics and subtotals for 5 columns which has made my file size to become 3 times larger.

Is there a way to say calculate the subtotals in memory on the fly and not in database?

Answer (score 1):

Import only the lowest level data - no subtotals. It's not clear whether your importing from a database or CSV. However, using the built-in Cognos groupings/aggregates will always calculate the subtotals/totals on the Cognos side, not the database/CSV side. You can confirm this from the generated SQL.

Comment: I was believing that Cognos was doing the subtotal calculation in memory but is not which I verified by looking at generated sql. I'm not importing from csv. I've given csv data sample above just to show how cognos is pulling data. I'm in ver 10.1.1. Do you know if I can say to do the subtotal calculation in memory and not pull from database? I would like to hear from you very quick as this is very urgent. Thanks.

Comment: What database are you on? What is an example of the subtotal calc in SQL? If you run the generated SQL direct against the database, does it take dramatically less time than Cognos runs the report in? There is no flag that I know of. This is just one of those things that usually works. If your export file has grown 3x in size, the issue with speed may be due to rendering rather than data processing.

Comment: Netezza is the DB. Example of subtotal calc is the subtotal for each departments as shown in the question. Sql takes only about 1 min but the report runs for about 7 min. Rendering could be a problem, so I tried with a row limit of 100. This has a gain of 1 min. or so but still 6 minutes is just too much for a query that ran in 1 min.

Comment: Post the generated SQL. Even so, a difference of 7x indicates major issues with the Cognos environment. Could be configuration related or network related. Subtotals are the symptom, not the cause, of your problem.

Comment: What is sql to do when the database session has ended in about a minute? I can give you the sql and excel dump but its pretty huge to post here. I guess I need to send it to your email. Can I have your id?

Comment: You can find the sql and csv output in this link. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17747414/sql%2C%20csv.7z

Comment: I took a look at the SQL and output but for the most part it seems rather business-specific. It really doesn't matter how complex the SQL statement is in Netizza - if it returns in a minute, thats pretty good. 7 minutes for Cognos to render indicates an issue there. Consult a Cognos admin to check settings. Consult a network admin to test the connectivity between server and client. Network could be further diagnosed by testing the difference between running the report as a job vs on demand. Heading out for vacation 10 days so wont be able to provide further assistance.